# HQL query results "cannot be used in this generic collection" when returning a subclass

Tags: nhibernate, hql

Given the following:

A Company has a collection of Product objects.
An Area has a collection of Product objects.
Any given Product has a Company and an Area.
SpecialProduct is a subclass of Product.

I'm using the following HQL query in NHibernate.

```
// return all SpecialProperty objects for a given company and area.
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("select product from Company as company " +
    "join company.Products as product " +
    "join product.Area as area " +
    "where company.Id = :coId " +
    "and area.Id = :arId " +
    "and product.class = MyNamespace.DomainModel.SpecialProduct ")
    .SetInt64("coId", companyId)
    .SetInt64("arId", areaId);
IList<SpecialProduct> specialProducts = query.List<SpecialProduct>();
```

When the 2nd statement above executes, I get an error stating:

Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]
The value "SpecialProduct" is not of type "MyNamespace.DomainModel.SpecialProduct" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value

(Note that the object shows in the message above as "SpecialProduct" because of a ToString() override in the SpecialProduct class.)

If I change the statement to return a list of the superclass, Product, like so...

```
IList<Product> products = query.List<Product>();
```

...then I don't get the error and a single matching object is returned in the list.  Examining this object in the debugger I see that appears to be, in fact, a SpecialProduct according to the ToString() override, but looking closer I see that it is an NHibernate proxy class.  If I try casting the object to SpecialProduct, the cast fails.  Hmmm...

I also checked in the database itself and confirmed that the record was saved as a SpecialProduct (based on the fact that there is a matching record in the joined-subclass table).

I need to get the results as a generic collection of SpecialProperty objects.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: The problem suddenly went away.  Due to some change elsewhere in the code (no changes to the query), the query is now returning actual instances of the class rather than NHibernate proxy's of the class. Go figure...  It would be nice to know **why** it started returning the actual object instead of a proxy in case this happens again.  :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. NH proxies inherit from the base type, not subclasses.

Hopefully, [this link](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html) will help.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Diego. It makes sense that a proxy reached by traversal from another object using a property that references the base type couldn't be cast directly to the subtype. In my situation, however, the reference is **within** an HQL query which also limits the return type ("...product.class = subtype"). In other words, I'm giving NH enough info for it to know in advance the type that should be returned. In addition, I'm asking for a list of the subtypes as the result of the query (not a list of objects that reference them). Isn't there a way to instruct NH to return the subtypes?

Comment: Maybe using CreateCriteria instead?  Something like `session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SpecialProperty)....List<SpecialProperty>();` perhaps?

Comment: @MylesRip: no. Best case scenario, it will work *sometimes* (been there) and it will break miserably as soon as you have a proxy for that instance already loaded in the session.

Comment: That's too bad. I was hoping to find a solution that could be applied at the time of the NHibernate query. I guess my only approach then would be to use the "backdoor" as needed (as described in your link above). Thanks for the help!